# Block matrix building matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

What would be the most efficient way to build this matrix given that I have each of the nxn matrices.

I was thinking of creating a cell array and iterating through that using a nested for loop but for large k this would be very inefficient..

[image]

Comment: `out = blkdiag(m1,m2,m3,m4,...),` and go from there reading the documentation for `blkdiag` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html

Comment: @bla But `k` varies so how can you use the line `blkdiag(m1, m2, m3, ...)` when you don't know `k`?

Comment: creating a cell array and iterating through it with k would be fine too. The key is you do `A = zeros(k*n, k*n)` and then copy stuff in at the appropriate places. If you're doing stuff like `A = [A, blah];`, that will be inefficient

Comment: @user3701257 you should upvote and accept answers that work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to use blkdiag with arbitrary number of input matrices:

```
m = {[1,2; 3, 4]; [10, 11, 12; 13, 14, 15; 16, 17, 18]};  %cell array of matrices
A = blkdiag(m{:})
```

You can then touch it up by copying matrices into the big matrix `A`

```
for(i=1:k-1)
    row_begin = 1 + (i-1)*n;
    row_end   = row_begin + n - 1;
    col_begin = 1 + i*n;
    col_end   = col_begin + n - 1;
    A(row_begin:row_end, col_begin:col_end) = B
end
```

etc...

If your matrix is *extremely* large but extremely sparse and your algorithm preserves sparsity, you may consider constructing a [sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, but you have missed the C_n in the first column. What would be the best way of doing?

Comment: look at how I did B and you should be able to figure that out